# How to apply list values to variables in a function and get a result list?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have a 3D list fp = {{x1, y1, z1}, {x2, y2, z2},...{x100, y100, z100}}, and I have a function resulting from a Fit

```
fitline = Fit[fp, {1, x, x^2, y, y^2, x y}, {x, y}]
```

then i would like to compare the fitted values, i. e. fitline(x1, y1), fitline(x2, y2), etc.,  to the original ones z1, z2, etc.

So how can I use each x in `fp[[All, 1]]` and each y in `fp[[All, 2]]` to generate a new list, say fdata consisting of {fitline(x1, y1), fitline(x2, y2), ...}? Is there any to do it without using embedded loops?

Comment: What version of Mathematica do you use?  Do you have access to LinearModelFit from version 7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming (hoping) that you have Mma version 7 so that youcan use `LinearModelFit` which allows extraction of many properties of the fitted model including  `"PredictedResponse"`. For example,

```
 ClearAll[x, y, data, pred];
 data = Flatten[Table[{x, y, Sin[x + y]}, {x, 5}, {y, 5}], 1];
 lm = LinearModelFit[data, {x, y}, {x, y}];
 pred = lm["PredictedResponse"];
 Transpose@Flatten[{Transpose@data, {pred}}, 1] // MatrixForm
```

gives

[image: data with predictions]

If you have to work with `Fit`, then you can do the following:

```
 lmf = Fit[data, {1, x, y}, {x, y}];
 fitfunc[x_, y_] := lmf[[1]] + lmf[[2, 1]] x + lmf[[3, 1]] y;
 predz = fitfunc @@@ data[[All, 1 ;; 2]];
 dataAndPredictions = 
 Transpose@Flatten[{Transpose@data, {predz}}, 1] // MatrixForm
```